# How big is a Game World in LibGDX?

Tags: libgdx

I know that the game world is like the whole game itself and most of the time, the developer sets the Screen to be a particular section of the Game World. However, how big is the Game World? 
For instance, when we run the default code for libgdx once we first create a project, a simple texture is shown with a red background. Does that mean that the Game World can be endlessly big? If we set the desktop launcher's size to be really big, does the red background still fill the whole launcher?

Comment: There is no such thing as a "Game World". You're rendering pixels to certain positions on the screen. Those pixels change depending on your code.

Answer (score 2):

The world can be as big as you want, up to reasonable limitations of the numbers you use to store information about the world. You get to pick both the types of numbers you use (integers or floats) and the metric you assign to those numbers: are they measuring tiles, pixels, feet, meters, furlongs?

If you use 64-bit integers to store information about the positions of things in your world, your world can go from `-2^63` to `2^63 - 1` in size. If you use floats, you have an even larger range.

Note that your choice here does have consequence: integers are all representable within the available range, but you don't have decimal points to do precise positioning, and you may need to convert things to a local floating-point coordinate frame to render them. Floats, on the other hand, allow you to do very fine fractional positioning but have precision errors the further you get from zero. Either choice might involve you doing more work somewhere else to translate between coordinate systems and representations using in your code to the ones expected by some third-party library (most notably the underlying graphics API).

But the main point is that the decision is yours to make.

Answer (score 0):

A game world is just an abstraction used to make drawing stuff to the screen simpler (would you rather manage coordinates at `(x,y) -> (160000000,160000000)`, or `(x,y)->(1600, 1600)`? The "world coordinate" is converted to screen coordinates and drawn on the screen via a series of mathematical operations involving a projection matrix. This matrix is used in a SpriteBatch (it's been a while since I have fiddled with libgdx, but I believe each SpriteBatch has a default projection matrix that maps the ratio of pixels per world coordinate to 1) to perform aforementioned mathematical operations. You can create custom projection matrices and set the sprite batch projection matrix for an almost infinite set of possibilities. The libgdx camera classes have projection matrices that you can use to set the batch matrix.

So, this all means that there really is an infinite number of places to "draw stuff". Well, mot really infinite technically, but infinite in practice. And if you don't like one coordinate system you can configure your own and set the SpriteBatch to render to that.